# extracting string before specific mark

Tags: python

I have a couple of file in two separate directories. Files from `directory1` always end with  `_config.txt`. Files from `directory2` always end with `_other.txt`. So for example,  `ABC_config.txt` would be from `directory1` and `ABC_other.txt` would be from `directory2`.  Is there a way I can extract the string right before the `_` mark so I can compare both names instead of having to check to see if `"ABC"` is in `file1` and `file2` and then making the comparison?
The function below would make the comparison between both files with the same content before the `_` mark.

```
def process(directory1, directory2):
     for file1 in os.listdir(directory1):
        for file2 in os.listdir(directory2):
            if .....
                file1 = os.path.join(directory1, file1)
                file2 = os.path.join(directory2, file2)
                helperProcess(directory1, directory2, file1, file2) #compares two files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> s1 = 'ABC_config.txt'
>>> s2 = 'ABC_other.txt'
>>> s1.split('_')[0] == s2.split('_')[0]
True
```

You can use `ntpath` to extract file name from its path.

```
>>> import ntpath
>>> ntpath.basename("/home/user/file.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
filename = 'ABC_config.txt.'
print filename.split('_')[0]
```

This would give output
`ABC`